# phonegap cordova unable to locate blackberry-nativepackager

Tags: command-line, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, cordova-3

I am trying to create a blackberry10 project with phonegap cordova command line tool. I am following through the phonegap document (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Cordova%20Command-line%20Interface) but keep running into the same problem.

When I run "cordova platform add blackberry10" in the terminal, it returns [Error: blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path. Aborting]

Does anyone know why and what am I missing? Why is it trying to locate the blackberry-nativepackager, instead of the webwork sdk?

All I want to do its just loading up an external url in bb10. Any better suggestion? Does anyone has any good tutorial/walkthrough on how to create a blackberry10 project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `nativepackager` thing is needed to create a package, even with WebWorks. You'll find it in `$BBNDK/host_10_x_xx_xxxx/linux/x86/usr/bin/blackberry-nativepackager` (adapt to your OS). You'll need to add this folder to your path. Doing this depends on your OS.

The easiest way to do this is to run the `bbndk-env` script, located in your NDK root directory.

Comment: I will give it a try. Will let you guys know how things go. Thanks!

Comment: yes I need to manually add the bbndk bin folder into my path! Detail information for cordova 3.0 can be found in http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide. BIG THANKS to kemaid and chadtatro

Answer (score 1):

Here's some updated documentation to align with Cordova 3.0. It will cover all the steps needed (including the NDK setup, which seems to be currently missing in your environment).

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_blackberry10_index.md.html#BlackBerry%2010%20Platform%20Guide